# How to convert a series of column by to_timedelta()

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert a series of columns by `to_timedelta` :

`df.filter(regex=("time.*")).apply(pd.to_timedelta)`

but I get this error:

`ValueError: ('expected hh:mm:ss format', 'occurred at index xyz')`

How could I efficiently change this time format? Is it possible by `to_timedelta`?

**Update**

An extract of the data:

[image]

Comment: Please post some sample data from `df`.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler The entire dataset is very big, I have posted a small part of it. These are the data I am trying to convert.

Comment: Thanks, @Simone! Assuming the DataFrame contents are strings that represent hours and minutes, I would try something like this: `(df.filter(regex=("tempo*")) + ':00').apply(pd.to_timedelta)`